# how to convert string to interface type in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have store value in local storage then I need this local storage value to store in interface type variable. but showing error as can not string to the interface type.

```
export interface MainData {
  name:string;
  rollNumber:number;
}
localStorage.setItem('currentUser',JSON.stringify(user.ua));
s:MainData[];
this.s = localStorage.getItem('currentUser'); // showing error here
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` in order to transform the string into an object

Comment: `JSON.parse('')`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is just: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))`

If you want something a bit more re-usable, you could leverage generics to define the return type...

```
export function hydrateFromLocalStorage<T>(key: string): T {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))
  }
  catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}

// example
const currentUser = hydrateFromLocalStorage<YourInterface>('currentUser');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a type **miss match type error**, 
You get this error because when you load item from the local storage, the item is type of string,

in order to fix this problem simply use JSON.parse():

`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));`